# Gradle Sync Error on IntelliJ IDEA for Android

Tags: android, android-studio, intellij-idea, android-jetpack, gradle-plugin

In an attempt to improve performance on my computer, I tried to configure IntelliJ IDEA for Android development. I have an ongoing project, which I simply imported into IDEA, and it builds perfectly. However, when it starts to sync the project, I get this error:

```
Cannot convert string value 'JETPACK_COMPOSE' to an enum value of type 'com.android.builder.model.AndroidGradlePluginProjectFlags$BooleanFlag' (valid case insensitive values: APPLICATION_R_CLASS_CONSTANT_IDS, TEST_R_CLASS_CONSTANT_IDS, TRANSITIVE_R_CLASS)
```

This project synced properly in Android Studio, but I want to know if there is any way to resolve this error on IDEA. Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The IntelliJ IDEA 2020.1 is not compatible with Android support 4. As a workaround you may use android-gradle-plugin 3.6.2 or use IntelliJ IDEA 2020.2 version. The RC build is available at https://www.jetbrains.com/idea/nextversion/

Comment: The [Stable Release for IntelliJ IDEA 2020.2](https://www.jetbrains.com/idea/download/) was released on July 27th. I downloaded it, and it resolved the issue. Thank you so much!